# Which User Role for Custom Post Type Menu - wp_nav

Tags: custom-post-types, menus, user-roles

I have a site with a custom post type "Streams".  I would like for my editor to be able to add steam post types to the main menu of the site, but he cannot see them under Appearance->Menus.

Which user role is associated with custom post type menu items (wp_nav not the dashboard menu).?

Thanks!

Comment: Only admin or super admin role has the capability to edit the menu. To let your editor edit the menu he will need to be one of those or you can add the 'edit_theme_options' capability to his role.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities

Comment: The role was set. The proper answer (in my case) is below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first guess would be that he needs to make sure the checkbox is checked for that particular CPT under Screen Options (top right of Appearance -> Menus).

Comment: Thanks! This is so obvious I always forget about it but it usually ends up being the reason something is not showing.